# How do you toggle background:url's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggleclass

I'm using Todd Moto's flaunt.js for navigation and want to toggle the hamburger image with another image, and back again, when the mobile-menu is revealed and closed.

The demo is here:

https://toddmotto.com/labs/flaunt-js

The tutorial is here:

https://toddmotto.com/flaunt-js-for-stylish-responsive-navigations-with-nested-click-to-reveal

Comment: There's plenty of information out there about how to modify a CSS value or add/remove classes from an element, especially using jQuery. What exactly are you having trouble with and what have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are plenty of ways to change the CSS background image. You can set it directly.

Example:

HTML: `<div id='my-box'></div>`
CSS:

```
#my-box {
    height: 518px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#my-box').style.backgroundImage =
    'url(' +
    'https://www.thebigduck.us/content/themes/big-duck/dist/images/dp03_v2.jpg' +
    ')';
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmz20uhy/